# How do I make Firefox use Chrome's built-in Flash plugin?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

How do I make Firefox use Chrome's built-in Flash plugin?

I assume I can simply symlink Chrome's Flash plugin in Firefox' plugin directory—which directories do Chrome and Firefox use to store their plugins?

Comment: Why exactly would you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome keeps the plugin in:

```
/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/{current_version}/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Internet Plug-Ins/Flash Player Plugin for Chrome.plugin/Contents/MacOS/
```

For me current_version is 16.0.912.63

Firefox uses Adobe mainstream version of Flash player, which is installed in:

```
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Flash Player.plugin/Contents/PlugIns/FlashPlayer-10.6.plugin/Contents/MacOS
```

The size difference is quite big (35MB mainstream against 16MB Chrome version). I actually tried to make such trick by making symbolic link to chrome version in place of mainstream version, but Firefox didn't like that (did not show any content where flash should be).

Looks like it's not that simple as it is in Linux.

**EDIT:**

It turns out that it actually is that simple:

> Copy Chrome's Flash plugin,

```
/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/16.0.912.63/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Internet Plug-Ins/Flash Player Plugin for Chrome.plugin
```

> to

```
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Flash Player Plugin for Chrome.plugin
```

> and they both work.

Comment: I *copied* Chrome's Flash plugin, `/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/16.0.912.63/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Internet Plug-Ins/Flash Player Plugin for Chrome.plugin` to `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Flash Player Plugin for Chrome.plugin`  (and, just for kicks, it's PDF plugin as well) **and they both worked**. Bravo sir!

Comment: Looks like it is that simple :). I will edit my answer to include your solution

Comment: But make sure that you still update the plugin on a regular basis.